# Spring application context reloading doesn't update bean registered by DelegatingFilterProxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, refresh, applicationcontext

In app we have functionality of update configuration on fly. It overrides application properties and call:

```
  ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)applicationContext).refresh();
```

We are also using  *DelegatingFilterProxy* to register Spring bean as a filter.

```
@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    DelegatingFilterProxy delegatingFilterProxy = new DelegatingFilterProxy("myFilter");
    delegatingFilterProxy.setContextAttribute(FrameworkServlet.SERVLET_CONTEXT_PREFIX + "dispatcher");

    return new Filter[] { delegatingFilterProxy };
}
```

When I reload application.properties I see that Spring reccreate all beans but DelegatingFilterProxy still using first version of filter bean (so all requests are filtered by stale filter with stale autowired beans on it)

Do you know why it happens how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you why it happens.

I'm assuming you're registering your `DelegatingFilterProxy` in a `WebApplicationInitializer` subclass, maybe an `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer` subclass.

Regardless, this class is completely independent of actions to the `ApplicationContext`. The Servlet container scans your classpath and finds Spring's `SpringServletContainerInitializer` which finds your `WebApplicationInitializer` implementation and runs it. The `DelegatingFilterProxy` is then registered specifying a bean name.

When the first request comes in to your server, the `DelegatingFilterProxy` will attempt to find its delegate in the `ApplicationContext` and set it to its delegate field. It does this only if its current delegate is `null`. So a refresh of the context won't affect it.

There are possible solutions [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6228).